# Set the initial value of the clock and setInterval () based on the seconds contained in the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to set the value of `timerOn`,``` timerTime``timerStart ``` for the watch to start count from 120 seconds? `const selectItem = this.props.items [1]` -> second object in array `items`({seconds: 120}). At the moment the clock begins to count from `3 min 22 sec`, and should be from `2 min`

All code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jcydop

**Snippet:**

---

```
const selectItem = this.props.items[1] //second 120
```

**App**

```
this.state = {

      items: [
        {
          name: 'A',
          description: 'Hello',
          second:  70
        },
        {
          name: 'B',
          description: 'World',
          second: 120
        }
      ],
      selectIndex: null
    };
  }
```

**Watch**

```
class Stopwatch extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      timerOn: false,
      timerStart: 0,
      timerTime: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      const selectItem = this.props.items[1]

      this.setState({
        timerOn: true,
        timerTime:  selectItem.second * 1000,
        timerStart: Date.now() - this.state.timerTime
      });
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({
          timerTime: Date.now() - selectItem.second * 1000
        });
      }, 10);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have a timer that starts at 2:00 (120 seconds) and starts counting up.

If that's the case, you can do it like this, initializing `timerTime` to 120 seconds (the value of `props.items[1]`) and every 10ms increment the time:

```
class Stopwatch extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      timerOn: false,
      timerTime: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      // Note: you could move this block of
      // code to the constructor if you want
      const selectItem = this.props.items[1]

      this.setState({
        timerOn: true,
        timerTime:  selectItem.second * 1000,
      });
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          timerTime: prevState.timerTime + 10
        }));
      }, 10);

  }
```

Incrementing by 10ms every 10ms will increment once per second. If you want the stopwatch to go faster, increment by a higher number, 100 or 1000ms.

If I've misunderstood and you want the counter to count down, you should set state as `timerTime: prevState.timerTime - 10`

I'm not sure if you're using `timerStart` in some other place, but it doesn't seem to be needed here.

Comment: I also need `timerStart` in function `startTimer()`. Delete `timerStart` from `startTimer()`?

Comment: I don't think you need `timerStart` at all.